# MySQL one-to-many relationship single query

Tags: mysql

I have this two tables. I'll make it as simple as possible:

```
Sample value in main_table:
id = 1

Sample value in details_table:
id = 1
type = book
name = harry potter

id = 1
type = paper
name = post it
```

The result I need is to get id with the name for those two types.

```
id    book            paper
1     harry potter    post it
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output suggests that you want to pivot the `type` and generate columns based on its value.  Assuming the only types which can appear are `book` and `paper`, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT t2.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 'book'  THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS book,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.type = 'paper' THEN name ELSE NULL END) AS paper
FROM main_table t1
INNER JOIN details_table t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: What is the MAX for?

Comment: @aozora This a pivot query, and the `MAX` will retain the non `NULL` value from each of the pivoted columns.

Comment: Thanks I don't know the proper term for what I am doing. Now I know it is pivot.

Comment: @aozora If you have a reasonable number of fixed columns you want to appear in the result, this approach works fine.  If you have a dynamic number of columns, then you might need dynamic MySQL for that (read: coding).

Answer (score 2):

Simply join the details table twice:

```
Select m.id, d1.name as book, d2.name as paper from main_table m 
join Details_table d1 on m.id =d1.id and d1.type = 'book'
join Details_table d2 on m.id =d2.id and d2.type = 'paper'
```

Comment: Nice answer too. But I like to just join once. I don't know if it might affect performance on bigger queries. Still a great answer